# LESS extend not working with Angular :host

Tags: angular, less, angular7

I have an angular component:

```
export class HeaderMainComponent { }
```

With the HTML:

```
<header>
  Some content
</header>
```

And LESS styles:

```
:host(.dark) {
  header { 
    &:extend(.dark all); 
  }
}

header {
  &.dark {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

I use the component as:

```
<header-main class="dark"></header-main>
```

The previous LESS code does not apply black background to header HTML tag.

I can only make it work if I use the following:

```
:host(.dark) {
  header { 
    background-color: black;
  }
}

header { }
```

Why isn't LESS `extend` working with Angular `:host`?

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you go to lesstester.com and paste both working and not working versions, you can get to the same output with some tweaking.. like removing header{} around &.extend and &.dark and adding header like :host(.dark) header{

Comment: @bestinamir could you post your working code on an answer? On your comment I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which worked for you:

```
:host(.dark) {
  header { 
     background-color: black;
  }
 }

header { }
```

Here's the tweaked code which didn't work for you:

```
:host(.dark) header {
  &:extend(.dark all); 
}    

&.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Here the output which is the same for both.

[image]